# how to go back to the previous menu on pressing the back button? - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, scrollview, swipe

i am developing an app, and this is the code. I have two questions.

mainactivity.java

```
package com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton flightInfoButton;
ImageButton airportGuideButton;
ImageButton visitorInfoButton;
ImageButton saaDcaButton;
ImageButton cargoButton;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    flightInfoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flightInfo);
    airportGuideButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.airportGuide);
    visitorInfoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.visitorInfo);
    saaDcaButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.saaDca);        
    cargoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cargo);

    airportGuideButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View V){

        setContentView(R.layout.airport_guide);

    }
  });
    visitorInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V){

            setContentView(R.layout.visitor_info);

        }
    });
    saaDcaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V){

            setContentView(R.layout.saa_dca);

        }
    });
  }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

so this is the java code. here after it goes into either airport_guide or saa_dca or visitor_info, if I press the back button , the app just closes instead of going back to the main menu. is this something to do with the activity life cycle and should i include something there? and if so please tell how. I am new to android development.

this is the saa_dca.xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/corporateProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/infoForAirline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/businessPolicy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/saftyAndSecurity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/trafficRights"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/securityPasses"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/photography"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mediaCentre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/customerRelations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/contactUs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

as you can see, there are ten image buttons here, but when this opens after clicking on the according button, all the buttons won't fit in the screen, I thought android provides scroll up and down by default if the buttons exceed the screen but apparently it is not the case.  so how do i include the swipe function for this to scroll up and down? and where should i include it? if you want the other xml codes, please ask .I will put them as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

not sure, but here is my assumption , you can override onBackPressed()

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

this one

You can keep track of which button are currently pressed. And when you click on back button, you know the tracked position, say its 5th position, just focus the button which is in the 4rth position.

Answer (score 1):

If your menu is in a fragment you can add it to the back stack.

[BackStack](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

Then when you press back it will go back to the previous menu before exiting (on another back button press)